# Having trouble with my candy crush style javascript game

Tags: javascript, html

`app.js`
the `startPage()` function gets called through the `onclick` in the html button, but when `createBoard()` gets called, i get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null.

I'm just wondering if there is anything i can do to fix this, or is there a fatal flaw with it in terms of having to restart from scratch. Thanks

````
//Initializing global variables
const grid = document.getElementById("grid");
const scoreDisplay = document.getElementById("score");
const width = 8;
const squares = [];
let score = 0;

const candyColors = [
  "url(images/red-candy.png)",
  "url(images/yellow-candy.png)",
  "url(images/orange-candy.png)",
  "url(images/purple-candy.png)",
  "url(images/green-candy.png)",
  "url(images/blue-candy.png)",
];

//Game Home Page

function startPage() {
  var myBut = document.getElementById("but");
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  myBut.removeChild(button);
  createBoard();
}
//create your board
function createBoard() {
  for (let i = 0; i < width * width; i++) {
    const square = document.createElement('div')
    square.setAttribute("draggable", true)
    square.setAttribute("id", i)
    let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * candyColors.length)
    square.style.backgroundImage = candyColors[randomColor]
    grid.appendChild(square)
    squares.push(square)
  }
}


// Dragging the Blocks
let colorBeingDragged;
let colorBeingReplaced;
let squareIdBeingDragged;
let squareIdBeingReplaced;

squares.forEach((square) => square.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart));
squares.forEach((square) => square.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd));
squares.forEach((square) => square.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver));
squares.forEach((square) => square.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter));
squares.forEach((square) => square.addEventListener("drageleave", dragLeave));
squares.forEach((square) => square.addEventListener("drop", dragDrop));

function dragStart() {
  colorBeingDragged = this.style.backgroundImage;
  squareIdBeingDragged = parseInt(this.id);
  // this.style.backgroundImage = ''
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragLeave() {
  this.style.backgroundImage = "";
}

function dragDrop() {
  colorBeingReplaced = this.style.backgroundImage;
  squareIdBeingReplaced = parseInt(this.id);
  this.style.backgroundImage = colorBeingDragged;
  squares[squareIdBeingDragged].style.backgroundImage = colorBeingReplaced;
}

function dragEnd() {
  //What is a valid move?
  let validMoves = [
    squareIdBeingDragged - 1,
    squareIdBeingDragged - width,
    squareIdBeingDragged + 1,
    squareIdBeingDragged + width,
  ];
  let validMove = validMoves.includes(squareIdBeingReplaced);

  if (squareIdBeingReplaced && validMove) {
    squareIdBeingReplaced = null;
  } else if (squareIdBeingReplaced && !validMove) {
    squares[squareIdBeingReplaced].style.backgroundImage = colorBeingReplaced;
    squares[squareIdBeingDragged].style.backgroundImage = colorBeingDragged;
  } else
    squares[squareIdBeingDragged].style.backgroundImage = colorBeingDragged;
}

//drop candies once some have been cleared
function moveIntoSquareBelow() {
  for (i = 0; i < 55; i++) {
    if (squares[i + width].style.backgroundImage === "") {
      squares[i + width].style.backgroundImage =
        squares[i].style.backgroundImage;
      squares[i].style.backgroundImage = "";
      const firstRow = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
      const isFirstRow = firstRow.includes(i);
      if (isFirstRow && squares[i].style.backgroundImage === "") {
        let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * candyColors.length);
        squares[i].style.backgroundImage = candyColors[randomColor];
      }
    }
  }
}

///Checking for Matches
//for row of Four
function checkRowForFour() {
  for (i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    let rowOfFour = [i, i + 1, i + 2, i + 3];
    let decidedColor = squares[i].style.backgroundImage;
    const isBlank = squares[i].style.backgroundImage === "";

    const notValid = [
      5,
      6,
      7,
      13,
      14,
      15,
      21,
      22,
      23,
      29,
      30,
      31,
      37,
      38,
      39,
      45,
      46,
      47,
      53,
      54,
      55,
    ];
    if (notValid.includes(i)) continue;

    if (
      rowOfFour.every(
        (index) =>
          squares[index].style.backgroundImage === decidedColor && !isBlank
      )
    ) {
      score += 4;
      scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
      rowOfFour.forEach((index) => {
        squares[index].style.backgroundImage = "";
      });
    }
  }
}

//for column of Four
function checkColumnForFour() {
  for (i = 0; i < 39; i++) {
    let columnOfFour = [i, i + width, i + width * 2, i + width * 3];
    let decidedColor = squares[i].style.backgroundImage;
    const isBlank = squares[i].style.backgroundImage === "";

    if (
      columnOfFour.every(
        (index) =>
          squares[index].style.backgroundImage === decidedColor && !isBlank
      )
    ) {
      score += 4;
      scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
      columnOfFour.forEach((index) => {
        squares[index].style.backgroundImage = "";
      });
    }
  }
}

//for row of Three
function checkRowForThree() {
  for (i = 0; i < 61; i++) {
    let rowOfThree = [i, i + 1, i + 2];
    let decidedColor = squares[i].style.backgroundImage;
    const isBlank = squares[i].style.backgroundImage === "";

    const notValid = [6, 7, 14, 15, 22, 23, 30, 31, 38, 39, 46, 47, 54, 55];
    if (notValid.includes(i)) continue;

    if (
      rowOfThree.every(
        (index) =>
          squares[index].style.backgroundImage === decidedColor && !isBlank
      )
    ) {
      score += 3;
      scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
      rowOfThree.forEach((index) => {
        squares[index].style.backgroundImage = "";
      });
    }
  }
}

//for column of Three
function checkColumnForThree() {
  for (i = 0; i < 47; i++) {
    let columnOfThree = [i, i + width, i + width * 2];
    let decidedColor = squares[i].style.backgroundImage;
    const isBlank = squares[i].style.backgroundImage === "";

    if (
      columnOfThree.every(
        (index) =>
          squares[index].style.backgroundImage === decidedColor && !isBlank
      )
    ) {
      score += 3;
      scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
      columnOfThree.forEach((index) => {
        squares[index].style.backgroundImage = "";
      });
    }
  }
}

// Checks carried out indefintely - Add Butotn to clear interval for best practise
window.setInterval(function () {
  checkRowForFour();
  checkColumnForFour();
  checkRowForThree();
  checkColumnForThree();
  moveIntoSquareBelow();
}, 100);```
===========================================================================================
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Candy Crush</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "but">
      <input id = "button" onclick = "startPage()" type="submit"/>
    </div>
    <div class="score-board">
      <h3>score</h3>
      <h1 id="score"></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="grid"></div>
  </body>
</html>
===========================================================================================
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Initializing global variables
const grid = document.getElementById("grid");
const scoreDisplay = document.getElementById("score");
const width = 8;
const squares = [];
let score = 0;

const candyColors = [
  "url(images/red-candy.png)",
  "url(images/yellow-candy.png)",
  "url(images/orange-candy.png)",
  "url(images/purple-candy.png)",
  "url(images/green-candy.png)",
  "url(images/blue-candy.png)",
];

//Game Home Page

function startPage() {
  var myBut = document.getElementById("but");
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  myBut.removeChild(button);
  createBoard();
}
//create your board
function createBoard() {
  for (let i = 0; i < width * width; i++) {
    const square = document.createElement('div')
    square.setAttribute("draggable", true)
    square.setAttribute("id", i)
    let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * candyColors.length)
    square.style.backgroundImage = candyColors[randomColor]
    grid.appendChild(square)
    squares.push(square)
  }
  squares.forEach((square) => square.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart));
  squares.forEach((square) => square.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd));
  squares.forEach((square) => square.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver));
  squares.forEach((square) => square.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter));
  squares.forEach((square) => square.addEventListener("drageleave", dragLeave));
  squares.forEach((square) => square.addEventListener("drop", dragDrop));
  start_interval();
}

// Dragging the Blocks
let colorBeingDragged;
let colorBeingReplaced;
let squareIdBeingDragged;
let squareIdBeingReplaced;

function dragStart() {
  colorBeingDragged = this.style.backgroundImage;
  squareIdBeingDragged = parseInt(this.id);
  // this.style.backgroundImage = ''
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragLeave() {
  this.style.backgroundImage = "";
}

function dragDrop() {
  colorBeingReplaced = this.style.backgroundImage;
  squareIdBeingReplaced = parseInt(this.id);
  this.style.backgroundImage = colorBeingDragged;
  squares[squareIdBeingDragged].style.backgroundImage = colorBeingReplaced;
}

function dragEnd() {
  //What is a valid move?
  let validMoves = [
    squareIdBeingDragged - 1,
    squareIdBeingDragged - width,
    squareIdBeingDragged + 1,
    squareIdBeingDragged + width,
  ];
  let validMove = validMoves.includes(squareIdBeingReplaced);

  if (squareIdBeingReplaced && validMove) {
    squareIdBeingReplaced = null;
  } else if (squareIdBeingReplaced && !validMove) {
    squares[squareIdBeingReplaced].style.backgroundImage = colorBeingReplaced;
    squares[squareIdBeingDragged].style.backgroundImage = colorBeingDragged;
  } else
    squares[squareIdBeingDragged].style.backgroundImage = colorBeingDragged;
}

//drop candies once some have been cleared
function moveIntoSquareBelow() {
  for (i = 0; i < 55; i++) {
    if (squares[i + width].style.backgroundImage === "") {
      squares[i + width].style.backgroundImage =
        squares[i].style.backgroundImage;
      squares[i].style.backgroundImage = "";
      const firstRow = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
      const isFirstRow = firstRow.includes(i);
      if (isFirstRow && squares[i].style.backgroundImage === "") {
        let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * candyColors.length);
        squares[i].style.backgroundImage = candyColors[randomColor];
      }
    }
  }
}

///Checking for Matches
//for row of Four
function checkRowForFour() {
  for (i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    let rowOfFour = [i, i + 1, i + 2, i + 3];
    let decidedColor = squares[i].style.backgroundImage;
    const isBlank = squares[i].style.backgroundImage === "";

    const notValid = [
      5,
      6,
      7,
      13,
      14,
      15,
      21,
      22,
      23,
      29,
      30,
      31,
      37,
      38,
      39,
      45,
      46,
      47,
      53,
      54,
      55,
    ];
    if (notValid.includes(i)) continue;

    if (
      rowOfFour.every(
        (index) =>
          squares[index].style.backgroundImage === decidedColor && !isBlank
      )
    ) {
      score += 4;
      scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
      rowOfFour.forEach((index) => {
        squares[index].style.backgroundImage = "";
      });
    }
  }
}

//for column of Four
function checkColumnForFour() {
  for (i = 0; i < 39; i++) {
    let columnOfFour = [i, i + width, i + width * 2, i + width * 3];
    let decidedColor = squares[i].style.backgroundImage;
    const isBlank = squares[i].style.backgroundImage === "";

    if (
      columnOfFour.every(
        (index) =>
          squares[index].style.backgroundImage === decidedColor && !isBlank
      )
    ) {
      score += 4;
      scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
      columnOfFour.forEach((index) => {
        squares[index].style.backgroundImage = "";
      });
    }
  }
}

//for row of Three
function checkRowForThree() {
  for (i = 0; i < 61; i++) {
    let rowOfThree = [i, i + 1, i + 2];
    let decidedColor = squares[i].style.backgroundImage;
    const isBlank = squares[i].style.backgroundImage === "";

    const notValid = [6, 7, 14, 15, 22, 23, 30, 31, 38, 39, 46, 47, 54, 55];
    if (notValid.includes(i)) continue;

    if (
      rowOfThree.every(
        (index) =>
          squares[index].style.backgroundImage === decidedColor && !isBlank
      )
    ) {
      score += 3;
      scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
      rowOfThree.forEach((index) => {
        squares[index].style.backgroundImage = "";
      });
    }
  }
}

//for column of Three
function checkColumnForThree() {
  for (i = 0; i < 47; i++) {
    let columnOfThree = [i, i + width, i + width * 2];
    let decidedColor = squares[i].style.backgroundImage;
    const isBlank = squares[i].style.backgroundImage === "";

    if (
      columnOfThree.every(
        (index) =>
          squares[index].style.backgroundImage === decidedColor && !isBlank
      )
    ) {
      score += 3;
      scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
      columnOfThree.forEach((index) => {
        squares[index].style.backgroundImage = "";
      });
    }
  }
}

// Checks carried out indefintely - Add Butotn to clear interval for best practise
function start_interval(){
    window.setInterval(function () {
      checkRowForFour();
      checkColumnForFour();
      checkRowForThree();
      checkColumnForThree();
      moveIntoSquareBelow();
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `defer` attribute to your script tag (optionally an `async` attribute as well).
`<script async defer src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

This will make sure the script executes only after the page loads and grid actually exists. As of now, its being executed immediately, before the DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` indicates that you're trying to invoke `appendChild` in a null variable. The error occurs in this line:

```
grid.appendChild(square)
```

Make sure that you're not assigning null to `grid` when initializing it.

```
const grid = document.getElementById("grid");
```